# Create a rough sketchy border around images or text with different sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I need to have some text, image and other elements to have a sketchy kind of hand drawn border around them. As an example here is one I created using the rough.js library.

[example rough border image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atBbp.png)

I have multiple ideas on how to solve this problem. I don't know which one might be the best or if there are other even better options.

The requirement is a rough and sketchy border around single images, multiple images around a gallery, titles or whole blog elements with text image and button. All that responsively of course.

My options so far are as follows:

#### Vanilla CSS

The Vanilla css way is to create a sketchy border kind of like seen here: https://codemyui.com/hand-drawn-border-buttons-css/

This does not really meet the requirement as it isn't really close to the desired end product. The example I added has multiple border lines which is not possible with vanilla css borders.

#### SVGs

Another option is to add the Borders as SVG elements to the code and just place them above the images. This seems to not work really well because for one I would like to just set a class on the element to achieve this border and also still keep the possibility to use both the before and after elements for other purposes.

Also I'd imagine this would get difficult with elements changing size and aspect ratio due to different screen sizes, similar to how border-image might not work.

### Rough.js

Rough.js is a great Library with a small size and great results. The Problem with this library is the randomness. The borders should have a distinct look for specific elements throughout the page. There seems to not be an option to deactivate said randomness (makes sense I guess).

Also I would rather not use any libraries.

### Canvas

Adding a Canvas through JS and creating a drawn border on top of the images does seem to work. The problem here is, that a lot of elements on the page then need to be recreated as canvases. I don't know if that really stems performance, but I would assume that it creates a lot of other difficulties with having that many elements being a canvas.

Also my knowledge of the canvas is really limited.

### Create SVGs

Another option I have been researching is creating svgs programmatically and adding them to the images. This seems to work so far when creating the svg with Rough.js. I don't know how complicated this would get for creating it in vanilla or jquery. And how functional that would be. Also how to add it to the images/text elements without using any pseudoelements.

### Creating a Paintworklet

A great solution for this is using a paint worklet and registerpaint. Then calling that through border-image. This approach I really like. The Problem here is the browser capability as a lot of browser including firefox do not support registerPaint. If there is a way to use this cross-browser I would really like this solution.

---

So these were my options so far. I would really appreciate some constructive criticism regarding what would be the best option for my scenario and/or if there are better options and solutions I haven't considered yet.

PS: I did not add any Code because it doesn't really matter. It should work independently of the underlying code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you need. The randomness can be controlled with seed parameter.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
canvas.width = 400
canvas.height = 200

const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
context.font = 'bold 20px monospace'
context.fillText('random rects:', 10, 13)
context.fillText('determined rects:', 10, 90)

const rc = rough.canvas(canvas)


// random rects
rc.rectangle(10, 20, 50, 50, { roughness: 2.8 })
rc.rectangle(80, 20, 50, 50, { roughness: 2.8 })
rc.rectangle(150, 20, 50, 50, { roughness: 2.8 })

// determined rects, with seed value for each call
rc.rectangle(10, 100, 50, 50, { seed: 3, roughness: 2.8 })
rc.rectangle(80, 100, 50, 50, { seed: 3, roughness: 2.8 })
rc.rectangle(150, 100, 50, 50, { seed: 3, roughness: 2.8 })
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://unpkg.com/roughjs@latest/bundled/rough.js"></script>
```

[rough-paint](https://github.com/pshihn/rough-paint) port rough.js to CSS Paint API, it can be a solution.

Comment: Hey this is exactly what I would have needed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

### svg filters `<feTurbulence>` and `<feDisplacementMap>`

You might try this approach described by [Daniel Jones (How to make rough edges with CSS and SVGs)](https://danieldarrenjones.com/articles/how-to-make-rough-edges-with-css-and-svgs)

#### Example 1: using random `<feTurbulance>`

```css
body {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

.resize {
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

.frame {
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.roughtEdges-after:after,
.frame-border {
  border: 10px solid #000;
}

.roughtEdges-after {
  position: relative;
}

.roughtEdges-after:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.roughtEdges-after:after,
.roughtEdges {
  filter: url(#roughtEdges);
}
```

```html
<h3>Resize frame</h3>
<div class="resize">
  <div class="frame roughtEdges-after">
    <span class="nofilter">
            Filter applied on border
        </span>
  </div>
  <div class="frame frame-border roughtEdges">
    Filter applied on border and text
  </div>
</div>

<!-- SVG filters -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
        <filter id="roughtEdges">
        <!-- you could also use 'fractalNoise' type option for a different result --> 
            <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.05" numOctaves="2" result="turbulence" />
            <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic" scale="5" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

#### Advantages:

- easily reusable via css `filter`property
- pretty responsive

#### Caveats:

- random noise

#### Example 2: noise generated by `<feImage>`

Described on [Codrops: SVG Filter Effects: Conforming Text to Surface Texture with feDisplacementMap](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/02/12/svg-filter-effects-conforming-text-to-surface-texture-with-fedisplacementmap/)

```css
body {
  font-size: 5em;
}

.resize {
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

.frame {
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.frame-border {
  border: 10px solid #000;
}

.roughtEdges-after {
  position: relative;
}
.roughtEdges-after:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 10px solid #000;
}

.roughtEdges-after:after,
.roughtEdges {
  filter: url(#roughtEdges);
}
```

```html
<!--
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/nAG8WN9.jpeg" alt="">
-->
<div class="resize">
    <div class="frame roughtEdges-after">
        <span class="nofilter">
            Filter applied on border
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="frame frame-border roughtEdges">
        Filter applied on border and text
    </div>
</div>

<!-- SVG filters -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">
    <filter id="roughtEdges" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
        <feImage preserveAspectRatio="none" href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQABAAQAAAAAAAD/7gAhQWRvYmUAZMAAAAABAwAQAwIDBgAAAhQAAAOhAAAGHv/bAIQAGxoaKR0pQSYmQUIvLy9CRz8+Pj9HR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHRwEdKSk0JjQ/KCg/Rz81P0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dH/8IAEQgAZABkAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/EAIYAAAMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAwQBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAADAAMBAAIDAQEAAAAAAAABAgMAERITIgRQIRQjMhEAAQQBAwIFAwQDAAAAAAAAAQARIQISMUFRYSJxgUIDE5GhMrHBUiPw0WISAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFD/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQAAAHqynON0RBi2bRmKvKhOi1M5cEjRxe8c4KpxZ7DOuuImqHTSZwvHgA8x59QdbyF094TiWEGC0LKJydyD2kVFYkvGKy7UgaQi74jU2OwO/SN86Feoxyd5jjBmpSJPSmkkUwmhexNPLRNGRbExgn0DVlA05gI6AOXAj0DoB//aAAgBAgABBQD8j//aAAgBAwABBQD8j//aAAgBAQABBQAMtqSInlAQ0y1Xps4QoxukQVIZ6bx6HhloRIMD2dGc2xJ7Ey9S022jgZJFJq3eaXnzJntkBZUyR0/Le60EwH4WCmrdghOQXPOKwUt+jHtcvUh+qb+qUVvP98/6iSqy0eYIjpo9gjouvkJ7UKXcFRPP5m6JEz5fKEwgtfsefxvrmaFQsuRJW5qvkktFXK0FCwxULD+ZsLHTaUQcd1qaZBygpY2yShQ8whLeRYhwWDGZZh2NsDp1IE20iyFMsRPHcgTfrJdM/wBnYEXQA8oV+yaZo+dLcJMl0QOrovLbm4QdtOPTboWddnlauh3QzJba6aHdUdBjyKFGZzaQJkrAIAG6MxxhUSZ2wuz54/D7LIWeRUTqWd2puLvpyiNwJ46MGVMo7hRbWWQc/wBB8lmwranbBPMxr0K2VGaIVSxIrQ7H105chwArKgcD48MQi0KlJ9o6qSrf5FqtTI0EzRNMGDKqFM6fpCwOx3fXMu8pz3Pfp9zrlOd179I/8/Dpt4e/VPXX79P/2gAIAQICBj8AR//aAAgBAwIGPwBH/9oACAEBAQY/ADe0Mhb2/BgsrO+3ijb3QHZVOX4wyexNTsvkk4jRD3SGJ3QtYObbptOoWPtmDCsL+gfVO8ZabIEMD+q7SK9ERxyv7CwbZGtQ/VCxn7+ab08q1AY5ZAg5HopqDEoGtTJ+iJsddAE3o180aNljDosG8NVkIr+qIL5JzAaE1TBQcuGVuuyNq17d09SZCBPaOq/layycu+jo15RFtQNVkA4ELutjc6oWBgbrEFxyoDh2KyqQSQheAN0GPyWKJLsdAsRDLPKOEb2YXJ2TO86pgZOyrTHuO6NSY2R4aUawzfimf6IEPyy0xvonFgCQzoFnsYK0nR0x1rBbdZUq8+aJ9WwVhY4ssgTc9USI8kM9NnRtbeAsrMGCN62TETt4oCwZNlD+a+T2xO6F9CYTt39E1yHWNT3KpqJMLGzOhUiEQSCXRB7XhkDV4VhWLELLIfJwj8f3QsR3DQdUavqsm0XCFRojZ2LsQURcR04W/au0gkrFyK11VrUC/wCv3TWPj/tGoshbXqrEBigAGHI5UliV3l7dEZ7rGFJBnlZYgdULt288q1hbEcL5JfHVWqS1lo0RyqguasiaQLJgBkiPctJT1fukFD3GzrVE1jeU9g7oAgYH7IkeTcLDydG9mJtyg0tun50WLOU1A7wfFHLQoVcxITEs+oTCxIrsmYko1bLEfdECo8E05OgLTGqeoaUCQLA6DhdoDvsjnqZVgS76I5mdgULnfhGwDQjdy1tlhYN15QsAMdSs8o/ijlr0VMWw9TqHdBstUMfyeXUa/uv7cei7n/zhRk26GOr7oOzKWxfZenFf/9k=" />
        <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="4" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="R" />
    </filter>
</svg>
```

#### Advantage:

- less randomness, since noise is difined by a static image

#### Caveats:

- ... still a lot of randomness, due to browser specific rendering deviations

So admittedly, none of the described methods is perfect.
But you might be able to find a combination that fits your needs.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your input. I tried this and played around with it some time and I think it doe not give me the desired result. Starting to believe it is impossible without coding deep canvas algorithms.